# If $AB \in \mathbb{N}$ and $B \in \mathbb{N}$, does it follow that $A \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

I am a bit confused myself, so I apologize if the answer to this particular question is trivial:

If $AB \in \mathbb{N}$ and $B \in \mathbb{N}$, does it follow that $A \in \mathbb{N}$?

Here, $\mathbb{N}$ is the set of natural numbers (i.e., the set of *positive integers*).

Comment: You mean like $\frac12\cdot 2 = 1$?

Comment: Indeed!  Thanks @DanielFischer.  =)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it does not follow that $A\in\mathbb{N}$. For example, consider $A=\frac{1}{2}$ and $B=2$. We have that $AB=1\in\mathbb{N}$ and $B=2\in\mathbb{N}$, but $A=\frac{1}{2}\notin\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: Thank you for your answer @ZevChonoles!  =)